# Objective C: change text of UIlabel from a Method

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I am pretty new in Objective C and I think I dont get how you work with objects.
I create a UILabel and I am able to set the Text and everything else.
But I would like to update it from a different method ..meaning I would like to change the text but I dont have the object in that method!

Thats how I set up the UILabel

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    UILabel *scoreLabel = [ [UILabel alloc ] initWithFrame:CGRectMake((self.view.bounds.size.width / 2), 0.0, 150.0, 43.0) ];
    scoreLabel.textAlignment =  UITextAlignmentCenter;
    scoreLabel.textColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
    scoreLabel.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];
    scoreLabel.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Arial Rounded MT Bold" size:(36.0)];
    [self.view addSubview:scoreLabel];
    scoreLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat: @"%d", 0];
}
```

Thats where I would like to change the text of the UILabel

```
- (void) touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
    self.crossView.alpha = 0.5;
    ...change scoreLabel.test 
}
```

both methods are in the ViewController!

maybe I could bind the UILabel to self? but how?

Answer (score 12):

You need to create a Property for your UILabel in your .h so you can modify it thoughtout your ViewController

In your .h Add this before `@end`

```
@property (strong, nonatomic) UILabel *scoreLabel;
```

Than in your viewDidLoad do this instead:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    _scoreLabel = [ [UILabel alloc ] initWithFrame:CGRectMake((self.view.bounds.size.width / 2), 0.0, 150.0, 43.0) ];
    _scoreLabel.textAlignment =  UITextAlignmentCenter;
    _scoreLabel.textColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
    _scoreLabel.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];
    _scoreLabel.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Arial Rounded MT Bold" size:(36.0)];
    [self.view addSubview:_scoreLabel];
    _scoreLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat: @"%d", 0];
}
```

Than later in your viewcontroller:

```
- (void) touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
    self.crossView.alpha = 0.5;
    _scoreLabel.text = @"CHANGED TEXT";
}
```

Comment: thanks for the quick answer! just one question is the underscore convention? is it mandatory?

Comment: It is basically another way to say `self.scoreLabel`. You can use `_` or `self`, whichever you prefer. You can synthesize your variable, like cscott530 did in his answer, so you do not need either, but Apple removed the need to do this and it just adds 1 more step when creating variables.

Comment: Yes worked perfect! with the underscore and the self. style !! thanks a lot

Comment: @user1354743 No prob! If you don't mind accepting the answer i'd greatly appreciate it :)

Answer (score 2):

As the additional option for defining the class property you can set the `tag` property for your `UILabel` instance and later when you want to update the label's content get this label using

```
UILabel *label = (UILabel *)[self.view viewWithTag:someTag];
```

This method searches the current view and all of its subviews for the specified view.

Answer (score 1):

in the header:

```
@property(nonatomic, retain) UILabel *scoreLabel;
```

and in the  .m (outside of any methods, typically right after the `@implementation [ClassName];` line):

```
@synthesize scoreLabel;
```

Then when you instantiate it, just do:

```
self.scoreLabel = [[UILabel alloc ] initWithFrame:CGRectMake((self.view.bounds.size.width / 2), 0.0, 150.0, 43.0)];
```

You will be able to reference it with `self.scoreLabel` anywhere in the .m

Answer (score 1):

In your interface write this

```
interface YourViewController{
    ....
    UILabel *scoreLabel
}
.....

@end
```

In your implementation you can easily acess your variable in this way

```
@Implementation YourViewController
....
- (void) touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
    self.crossView.alpha = 0.5;
    scoreLabel.text = @"Your Text"
}
....
@end
```

Answer (score 0):

To set a text/string in your UILabel use:

```
self.yourLabel.text=@"Your String";
```